# remove ugly border and dirty image symbol in css from spritesheet images

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border, render, outline

Firstly I wish to remove a white border from an image that i obtained from a spritesheet of png format, the problem is even after I've used:

```
border:0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
outline:none;
overflow:hidden;
border-collapse:collapse;
```

[image: ugly order]

white border still persists I used png so as to save transparency.

Secondly whith ie i see a dirty square on all of my sprite images. I used IE 11 for this.
[image: dirty image symbols]

Comment: Does your image have the white border in it?

Comment: thanks! unfortunately it doesn't all transparent . apart from that even when i  resize the image width and height the problem still persisits.

Comment: On a blue background, first show your image. Let's see what you really have.

Comment: @itsols [here this is the spritesheet itself](http://imgur.com/CwG3yl0)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:I sorted the first half by removing ugly border

```
clip:rect(10px,160px,70px,10px);
```

Bout how do i remove ugly image?

Comment: What exactly is your 'ugly image'? I don't quite get what you're trying to remove. Perhaps a screenshot of your **ugly image** highlighted will give someone else a better idea of what you mean.

Comment: @itsols In the bottom image I have included all the sprites. In it you can see a square next you login button (top left of login button in the bottom picture)